# Labeling Coordinate Based on Dictionary Information

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is my dictionary information

```
Z = {1: [[7,0],[7,1]], 
     2: [[3,4],[2,4]],
     3: [[0,3],[4,6]]}
```

Below is my coordinate array

```
X = [[7,0],[0,3],[3,4],[4,6],[7,1],[2,4]]
```

What I want to produce is this

```
 Y = [1,3,2,3,1,2]
```

So basically Y is labeling coordinate X based on information from Z. How can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick poke at your problem:

```
Z = {1: [[7,0],[7,1]], 
     2: [[3,4],[2,4]],
     3: [[0,3],[4,6]]} 
# Below is my coordinate array

X = [[7,0],[0,3],[3,4],[4,6],[7,1],[2,4]]

# What I want to produce is this

Y1 = [1,3,2,3,1,2]

Y = []
for coord in X:
    hit = None
    for k in Z:
        if coord in Z[k]:
            hit = k
            break
    Y.append(hit)

print(Y)
print(Y1)
```

Comment: Note that this solution defaults to only finding the first hit if there are multiple, provides `None` for coordinates that have no match and doesn't perform as well as the equivalent comprehension (which would arguably also be more pythonic)

Comment: The above code is one of many solutions to your problem. Note that it also handles the case where an input coordinate is not found in your Z dict.  The code looks through the list value of each dict entry for a match to the coord under scrutiny. As soon as it finds a match, it breaks out of the loop for that check. If not found, the default key value of 'None' is used.

Comment: @Grismar Sometimes the best, most Pythonic solution is not the best answer for a newer programmer. It's more important to be able to understand basic concepts and logic when first starting out.

Comment: Which is why I didn't downvote your answer, just providing some context for those that find it and may think this is "the way to do it". As a side effect, it also points out some assumptions you are making with regard to OP's question, which is incomplete. (note that the other answer assumes the opposite)

Answer (score 0):

If the structures are not too big, you can invert the Z and make the pairs into the dictionary keys. But lists are mutable, so you have to convert them to tuples:

```
Z = {1: [[7,0],[7,1]], 
     2: [[3,4],[2,4]],
     3: [[0,3],[4,6]]}
X = [[7,0],[0,3],[3,4],[4,6],[7,1],[2,4]]

z = {tuple(p):k for k,l in Z.items() for p in l}
{(7, 0): 1, (7, 1): 1, (3, 4): 2, (2, 4): 2, (0, 3): 3, (4, 6): 3}

Y = [z[tuple(p)] for p in X]
[1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This answer assumes there are no duplicates for coordinates and no coordinates are looked up that don't exist.